# Upgrading from iText 5.0.4 to later/latest versions - problems?

Tags: itext

I have iText version 5.0.4 installed and it has been working well.  I was not aware at the rate new versions are being created.
Has anyone jumped from a similar version to a much later version and did you have any problems ?

I am experiencing a problem reading a few pdf's where pdfReader is failing when merging multiple pdf's into a single pdf and as I have not been able to identify the reason for the problem wanted to try upgrading as a test.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which exception you're getting, but I can see three possible causes:

1. Closing streams, more specifically closing `PdfReader`, is now a responsibility of the developer, rather than a responsibility of iText. You may have to add or move `reader.close()` invocations.
2. We are less tolerant with respect to using broken PDFs (because using a broken PDF as input can lead to unexpected, incomplete results). We now throw an `InvalidPdfException` more often. (You can work around this by setting the `debugmode` to `true`).
3. There's a known problem (already fixed in the trunk) with 5.5.1 with respect to `PdfCopy`. If you use iText 5.5.0, this problem doesn't occur.
4. If one of your PDFs is encrypted, you'll need to make sure you also upgrade the BouncyCastle version. Mixing BouncyCastle versions leads to unpredictable errors. Check the POM file for each iText version to know which BouncyCastle is required.
5. If you're using `PdfWriter` to merge documents, you're doing it wrong.

Pick your answer depending on the exception you're getting.

Comment: I have set up a test with 2 pdf's.  Both pdf's can be opened and read without error using adobe pdf reader.  When merging the pdf's I am processing the known good one first and this all works fine, then I process the one that I know fails and am just using for this test to try and determine why the exception occurs.

I am working in RPG on an IBM iSeries calling the java classes.

The error I get is as follows;
Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable when calling method "<init>" with signature "(Ljava.lang.String;)V" in class "com.itextpdf.text.pdf.reader"

Comment: Aha, I'll add another bullet to my list.

Comment: Ok Thank you.  I have now checked the pdf properties and as you suspected the pdf does have Password Security - Document open Password = No, Permissions Password = Yes. Where can I find a matrix of compatible versions of itext and BouncyCastle ?

You also mention I am doing it wrong ?  How should I be doing this ?

Comment: Merging PDFs is done with `PdfCopy`, not with `PdfWriter` as has been explained many times on StackOverflow. There is no need for a matrix of compatible versions of iText and BouncyCastle: each version of iText works with exactly one version of BouncyCastle. That version can be found in the POM file (where else?). For instance in the version tagged 5.5.1, you can find the POM file here: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/HEAD/tree/tags/iText_5_5_1/itext/pom.xml (Under dependencies, you see a dependency on BouncyCastle 1.49.)